# Why does this Haskell code fail?

Tags: haskell

I have the following code (related to Project Euler's problem 34):

```
fac :: Int -> Int
fac = foldr1 (*) . enumFromTo 1

fe :: Int -> Bool
fe = (==) =<< (sum . map fac . digits 10)

fes :: [Int]
fes = filter fe [3..]
```

`fac` works fine, `fe` works fine, yet `fes` gives:

```
*** Exception: Prelude.foldr1: empty list
```

Interestingly, if I start the list with 145 (`fe` returns True here), it works for that number, then raises the Exception.

Why does this code fail? It seems like a perfectly normal application of `filter` with a function that clearly works and a regular list of numbers that work with that function individually.

Comment: Your code is full of point-free unreadability. Somehow or other, `fac` is being called with an argument less than 1, causing the list argument to `foldr1` (a terribly shady function) to be empty.

Comment: @dfeuer Bah, I think the only hard to read part is the `(==) =<<`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I wouldn't necessarily write it like that in actual 'production' code; I do these kinds of exercises mainly to experiment with Haskell. The same goes for the use `foldr1 (*)` instead of `product`; your point about `foldl'` vs `foldr` however, and @dfeur's point of the 'shadiness' of `foldr1` is certainly a good one . Had I used `product` here, I wouldn't have run into that problem but I also wouldn't have learnt these things. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `fac` fails with digit `0`, for which its list is empty. You can try

```
fac = foldr (*) 1 . enumFromTo 1
```

By the way `foldl'` (from `Data.List`) is probably better than `foldr` here, also there's a predefined `product` function.